# Setting CSS width does not seem to work with Flot graphs in @media print

Tags: css, flot

I have a screen that displays two flot graphs side-by-side quite happily.

I want to be able to print the graphs so I've set up an @media print clause with CSS like this:

@media screen
{
    div.plot {
        float: left;
        font-family: arial;
        width: 575px;
        height: 300px;
    }
}

@media print
{
    div.plot {
        float: left;
        font-family: arial;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
    }
}

My HTML looks like this:

```
        <div id="graph" class="plot"></div>
        <div class="plot" style="width:50px"></div>
        <div id="graph2" class="plot"></div><p></p>
```

As far as I can see, the printed version should produce two graphs, each 300 px wide.

What happens is that I get two graphs which still have the larger 575px width which then run into each other.

Is my understanding that CSS width controls the width of the graphs correct, or do I have to use another CSS control to fix the width of the graphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this work perfectly for me :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>test </title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    div.plot { float: left; font-family: arial; width: 575px; height: 300px;border:1px solid red; }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
    div.plot { float: left; font-family: arial; width: 300px; height: 300px;border:1px solid red; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="graph" class="plot"></div>
    <div class="plot" style="width:50px"></div>
    <div id="graph2" class="plot"></div><p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Your error probably lies where/how you defined your `@media print`.

Else it might be your **div id="graph/2"** that cause the problem... (if you have an `img` inside it that is too big for example) (try to add `overflow:hidden`!)

PS : for easy switching between `media` and `print` css, I use the [web developper toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/).

Comment: Thanks for testing it for me, needless to day, when I tried your solutions, neither would work for me..I guess that's just my luck.

Comment: The overflow:hidden did stop the graphs running into one another but unfortunately didn't shrink the graphs so that I could see each graph in its entirety.

Comment: It really seems to be a matter of the inside content of `#graph` being too big for its space. I don't know what elements are created in the div, but you could try to resize them in CSS (`#graph *, #graph2 * {max-width:300px;}` for example). Can't help you much more, as I've never played with flot graph.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely that when you call `$.plot`, it creates canvas elements inside your `#graph` placeholder.  Those canvas elements use the size of your placeholder, **when `plot` is called**, to set their own width and height.  When you hit Print, that changes the stylesheet to the print version, but you would also need to re-call `$.plot` or use the flot [resize plugin](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/resize.html).

Comment: Is the resize plug-in something else that I need to download or is it part of flot and I just need to make a call?  Just in case it matters, I have to get this to work with IE6...

Comment: it would have come as a separate file in the flot zipfile.  You will need to include the script `jquery.flot.resize.js` after you include `jquery.flot.js`.